# DjangoQ: 'str' object has no attribute 'user' when accessing `request.user`

Tags: django

I am using Django Q to schedule my python script which is inside views.py.

However, when running on my cluster, it doesn't fetch the logged in user. Instead, it gives an error:

```
11:24:50 [Q] ERROR Failed [early-finch-black-salami] - 'str' object has no attribute 'user' : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\MyProjects\djangocrawler\django_q\cluster.py", line 430, in worker
    res = f(*task["args"], **task["kwargs"])
  File "D:\MyProjects\djangocrawler\crawl\views.py", line 281, in ScraperA
    ids=request.user.username
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'user'
```

I am using `request.user` to get the detail of current logged in user. It is working fine in another view.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be able to help you better if you post your code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include the full error message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you wrote a view function that expects to receive a Django [`HttpRequest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) object, and then wanted to use the same function as a background job.

The problem is that--because the background job could be run in a different process or even on a different machine--its arguments must be serializable. Django Q is probably serializing your [`HttpRequest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) into a string before sending it to the worker, which then throws the error you see about the `str` object not having a `user` attribute.

You should try rewriting your background job to not depend on the entire [`HttpRequest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects). Instead, give the user ID to your background job as a string or integer. Your job can then use the Django ORM to get a [`User`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) object from the user ID.

*(If this guess is incorrect, forgive me. Feel free to post additional information about your problem.)*

Comment: Actually I have scraper script which scraps data into csv file  i have multiple scraper so to create unique csv to each scraper i am using Django logged in user as unique name it is working fine when normally just clicking on scrap button it fetches the logged in user details but when i am scheduling my scraper using Django Q that is  where I am getting an error it doesn't recognize Django user.

Comment: @OsaidKamal, if what you are building is a web scraper, then why is your scraping logic in a Django view?

Comment: Because using scraping logic other than views.py i am not able to filter scrapers from database according to user id

Comment: @OsaidKamal, ok then. Just like I said in my answer, write your scraping functions to only depend on the user ID--NOT the entire HttpRequest object.